# How to sort files based on the last upload time?

Tags: php

I have some files in my website and I want to display them, here's my script:

```
<?php 

    // open this directory 
    $myDirectory = opendir(".");
    // get each entry
    while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory)) {$dirArray[] = $entryName;} closedir($myDirectory);
    $indexCount = count($dirArray);
        echo "$indexCount files<br/>";
    sort($dirArray);

    echo "<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=5 cellspacing=0 class=whitelinks><TR><TH>Filename</TH><th>Filetype</th><th>Filesize</th><th>Upload Date</th></TR>\n";

        for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) 
        {
            if (substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1) != ".")
            {
            echo "<TR>
            <td><a href=\"http://didieksuriadi.ml/bullshit/$dirArray[$index]\">$dirArray[$index]</a></td>
            <td>".filetype($dirArray[$index])."</td>
            <td>".filesize($dirArray[$index])."</td>
            <td>".date("H:i:s # d-F-Y.",filemtime($dirArray[$index]))."</td>
                </TR>";
            }
        }
    echo "</TABLE>";
    echo date("h:i:sa");
?>
```

The problem is that, that script doesn't list all my files based on the upload time, what I want is that the most recent uploaded file should show up first so that I wouldn't have to scroll down to see the newest file. The demo can be seen at http://didieksuriadi.ml/bullshit/

Comment: In your case, you could just reverse the for loop.

    `for($index=$indexCount-1; $index>=0; $index--)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you sorted it but not by `filemtime()`.  Also, that's a lot of code:

```
array_multisort($times = array_map('filemtime', $files = glob("*")), SORT_DESC, $files);

foreach($files as $key => $file) {
    // echo HTML and stuff
    echo "{$file}<br>";
    echo "{$times[$key]}<br>";
}
```

- Use `glob()` to get all files in an array `$files`
- Pass `filemtime` to `array_map()` to get an array of `$times` for each file
- Sort `$files` array by `$times` array using `array_multsort()`
- Loop through the `$files` and use `$file` and `$times[$key]` for the file's time

Comment: Can you write the complete code ? I tried it but it didn't work