# PHP chdir issues

Tags: php, dynamic-arrays, chdir

**My Directories:**

- Main: "WWW" (Here are my php scripts and subfolders)
- "www/images" (This is where the images sent by users are stored)

**My scripts are:**

**- Switch.php**

```
<?php
include 'getdir.php';
switch (count($files)) {
case '1':
$fname = "database.php";
$fhandle = fopen($fname,"r");
$content = fread($fhandle,filesize($fname));
$content = substr_replace($content, ', '.'"'.$files[0].'"', -6, 0);
$fhandle = fopen($fname,"w");
fwrite($fhandle,$content);
fclose($fhandle);
break; //dance
}
?>
```

> In this script we use a switch to check if a file exists inside
>   "www/images"
>
> The file is represented in array by "$files[0]" var, which is provided
>   by the script "getdir.php" and if a file exists, we will create a
>   line of code inside the file "database.php" which is located in "www"
>   (the main folder of all scripts)

**And finally we can explain our next script "getdir.php"**

**- getdir.php**

```
<?php 
$dir = "images"; //Our files directory;
chdir($dir);
array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', ($files = glob("*.{jpg,png}", 
GLOB_BRACE))), SORT_REGULAR, $files); //Get an array list for dynamic 
files purposes;
?>
```

> The script "getdir.php" needs to return information for "switch.php", but it only
>   takes the "images" directory and does not consider the directory "www"
>
> The "switch.php" needs to store information in "database.php" located
>   in "www" (one level below) of ("www/images").

**Because 'chdir' in "getdir.php" the output's of "switch.php" and "getdir.php" are as follows:**

**"getdir.php" output;**

> Warning: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) in
>   C:\phpdesktop-chrome-57.0-rc-php-7.1.3\www\getdir.php on line 3

**"switch.php" output;**

> - Create a file "database.php" in "images" directory and store the information inside it.
>
> But this is not the result that I need and I've tried to do several
>   things, such as "//chdir" or
>   "$dir=[" images "," www "];" and many
>   other things but no success.

**Summary of everything:**

- I need the informations located in the directories "images" and "www" and not only the directory "images"
- I would like to store the information obtained by "switch.php" in the file "database.php" located in "www" instead of creating a new file "database.php" in "images"

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Problem fixed: "$dir = (__DIR__ . "/../www/images");" and "$fhandle = fopen(__DIR__ . '/../www/database.php', "r");" and we solve all bugs.

Comment: Please never post solutions as comments.  If you have self-solved, we welcome you to post your solution as an clear, educational, formatted answer.  After a short while, you will be able to "accept" your own answer.  I don't think you need `SORT_REGULAR` https://stackoverflow.com/a/37059539/2943403 . Also, http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php has a white-box Note that says: _If you just want to get the contents of a file into a string, use file_get_contents() as it has much better performance than the code above._

Comment: Do you need a `swtich-case` block? or would a simple `if` do the job? Finally, I have concerns about the purpose of `database.php`.  Why are you saving data, which seems better suited to a database entry to a `.php` file?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on "[PHP function fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)", I'll try that later.

"SORT_DESC" was used in the topic if you has mentioned, I tried to use the glob flags, but they did not match what I expected

so I used "SORT_REGULAR" which is provided in the following documentation: [PHP multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: @mickmackusa And I'm not storing important information inside the file, it's just public information.

Well the switch .. it performs faster for this task, exactly for what I need. I will be editing the topic when I have more time, thanks for your review.

Comment: Do you actually have more than one case inside the switch block?  How many do you have?

Comment: @mickmackusa 7 blocks.